# Creating global file input

Tags: java, fonts, io, overriding, program-entry-point

In my program, I already created several global variables, but it doesn't work with loaded files.

I load a .ttf file and create a Font-type variable (Or is it a constant?) for it:

```
public class Project extends JPanel implements Runnable
{

 [...] //global variables

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FontFormatException
 { 
  InputStream input = Project.class.getResourceAsStream("slkscre.ttf");   
  Font Silkscreen = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, input);

  @Override
  public void run()
  {
   [...]
  }
}
```

The problem is that if I'd like to make some operations, it can't detect `SilkScreen`, which means (I think at least) that variables in  `main` are not public.

Anyway, if I do it this way:

```
public class Project extends JPanel implements Runnable
{

 InputStream input = Project.class.getResourceAsStream("slkscre.ttf");   
 Font Silkscreen = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, input);

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FontFormatException
 { 

  @Override
  public void run()
  {
   [...]
  }
}
```

I got the error `unreported exception FontFormatException; must be caught of declared to be thrown`. I'm new at Java programming so I'd like to ask that what does it mean?

The same happens either if `input` is declared before `main` and `Silkscreen` is declared in `run` of if both of them are declared in `run`.

So the main question is how to make an input and a font from it public - or at least, available in `run`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that if I'd like to make some operations, it can't detect SilkScreen, which means (I think at least) that variables in main are not public.

Correct. Local variables are not visible outside of the method or block they are declared in.

The most straightforward solution is to declare the variables in your class and initialize them inside of the main method (or in a constructor).